# Large variance implies small probability of being in interval

Tags: probability, variance

Let $X$ be some random variable on a real interval $[0,\infty)$. Let $[a,b]\subset [0,\infty)$. Intuitively, it seems reasonable that if the variance of $X$ denoted by $\sigma_X^2$ is large compared to the size of the subset $b-a$, then the probability of being inside the subset should be small (if it was high then the variance would be small)

I am thus looking for a bound of the type

$P(a\leq X\leq b)\leq f(\sigma_X,a,b)$

where $f$ is some function that decreases as $\sigma_X$ gets larger (and probably increases with $b-a$).

There are many bounds, as can be seen already on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_inequalities#Probability_theory_and_statistics), but most of them show that if the variance is small then the probability of being far away from the mean is small (e.g. Chebyshev/Markov bound). I want the opposite: If the variance is large then the probability of being in any given (small) interval is small. I have unfortunately not manages to adapt those bounds to what I need (or if there is an existing one not recognized it as such)

Comment: Probability of being far away = 1 - probability inside, you can `flip' the event (take the complement) to have the inequality you want.

Comment: @Lee David Chung Lin: Unfortunately that didn't work, I either get a lower bound instead of an upper bound or I get an upper bound that increases with $\sigma_X$ instead of decreasing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why you cannot find a bound is because it doesn't exist.  You can make the variance arbitrarily large, but this doesn't force the probability of being in a pre-specified interval to tend to a nontrivial upper bound asymptotically unless the support is finite.

To see why, define for $a < b < c < d$ and $\theta \in (0,1)$ a random variable $$f_X(x) = \begin{cases} \frac{\theta}{b - a}, & a \le x \le b \\ \frac{1-\theta}{d-c} & c \le x \le d. \end{cases}$$ Then $$\operatorname{E}[X] = \frac{(a+b)\theta + (c+d)(1-\theta)}{2},$$ and $$\operatorname{Var}[X] =\frac{1}{12} \theta  \left(4 \left(a^2+a b+b^2\right)+2 \left(-3 (a+b) (c+d)+c^2+4 c
   d+d^2\right)\right)-\frac{1}{4} \theta ^2 (a+b-c-d)^2+\frac{1}{12} (c-d)^2.$$  In the special case where $a = b-1$ and $d = c+1$, we get $$\operatorname{Var}[X] = \frac{1}{12} + (c-b+1)^2 \theta(1-\theta),$$ and it becomes immediately apparent that this can be made arbitrarily large by increasing the difference $|c-b|$; yet $\Pr[b-1 \le X \le b]$ remains **constant** with respect to the parameter $\theta$; in turn, then, this probability can remain arbitrarily large.

Comment: Thank you very much, that was very clear!

Comment: @Shinja: you can also upvote solutions you like

Comment: @Alex: I tried, but don't have the required 15 reputation yet. My vote is recorded but not publicly displayed.