# Maximal value of integral over a fixed-length interval of the convolution

Tags: calculus, integration, optimization, definite-integrals, convolution

Let $f$ be function from $\mathbb{R}\rightarrow [0,1]$ with $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}dtf(t)=1$. Define
$\beta[f](\tau)=\max_t\int_{t}^{t+\tau}dt'f(t')$
i.e. $\beta[f](\tau)$ is the maximal value of the integral of $f$ over any (simply connected) interval of length $\tau$.

Let $(f\star f)(t)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}dt'f(t')f(t-t')$ be the self-convolution of $f$.
I am wondering if there are strong bounds on $\beta[f\star f](\tau)$ given by $\beta[f](\tau)$. It is relatively easy to show that $\beta[f\star f](\tau)\leq\beta[f](\tau)$, and some other bounds follow directly from this together with $\beta[f](\tau+\tau')\leq\beta[f](\tau)+\beta[f](\tau')$.

I am more looking for something like
$\beta[f\star f](\tau)\leq\beta[f](\tau')$
for some $\tau'<\tau$. Preferably $\tau'$ would be some function of $\tau$ and maybe some property of $f$, like the variance. In other words, if the integral over the self-convolution achieves a certain value over integrals of a given length, then I want to show that the original function achieves this value for strictly smaller intervals.

The intuition for this comes from the fact that under convolution, the variance increases, i.e. $\sigma_{f\star f}^2=2\sigma_{f}^2$. However one cannot derive bounds on integrals over some intervals just based on the variance, see my previous [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1933972/large-variance-implies-small-probability-of-being-in-interval). I am still hoping that such a bound exists nonetheless for the convolution.

If $f$ needs properties such as continuity or similar for this to hold, then they can be assumed for now.

Comment: Why is this tagged "optimization"? Some context seems to be missing between finding a tighter bound and optimization. Is it a situation where $\int f$ is feasible but you cannot do self-convolution? I'm just curious and I think this question is very interesting.

Comment: That may be a mistake on my part. It is simply tagged with optimization since I am looking for a bound on a maximum, so optimization techniques may be applicable.